# Submit form from a link with param

Tags: javascript, html, forms, parameters, hyperlink

I'm trying and searching now for days and can't find an answer.
My problem is this: I use a Hyperlink and Javascript to submit a form, but I also need to submit a parameter with the link. The code looks like this:

```
<form action="Action.jsp" method="post" id="form-id">
  <input .../>
  ...
  <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item" varStatus="vs">
    <a href="Action.jsp?id=${vs.count}" 
       onclick="javascript:document.forms['form-id'].submit(); return false">
       ${vs.count}
    </a>
  </c:forEach>
</form>
```

If I leave away the `return false` the param id is transferred but the other `<input .../>` parameters not and vice versa. How you see I can't use a `<input type="hidden" .../>` param, because I need only the param of the link.

If you please could help me, I would be grateful....

Comment: Please give us the rendered HTML output. Not some gibberish language no one wants to understand.

Comment: `methode="post"` should be `method="post"`, by the way.

Comment: `<a href="Action.jsp?id=1" 
         onclick="javascript:document.forms['form-id'].submit(); return false">
         ID 1
      </a>
      <a href="Action.jsp?id=2" 
         onclick="javascript:document.forms['form-id'].submit(); return false">
         ID 2
      </a>` This would be the rendered HTML output (mor or less)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a hidden `input` outside the loop, you can set the value of that input before submitting:

```
<form action="Action.jsp" methode="post" id="form-id">
  <input .../>
  <input type="hidden" id="button-id"/>
  ...
  <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item" varStatus="vs">
    <a href="Action.jsp" 
       onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('button-id').value=${vs.count};document.forms['form-id'].submit(); return false">
       ${vs.count}
    </a>
  </c:forEach>
</form>
```

Comment: Personally, I'd also extract the JavaScript code in a function to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your parameter into the action property of form as well.  This determines what URL the page is submitted to when submit occurs.

So you will probably need to use javascript to change this property value when the link is clicked to where it behaves like this.

```
<form action="Action.jsp?id=${vs.count}" method="post" id="form-id">
```

When you remove `return false`, what you are in essence doing is just getting the default behavior of the link after the form quickly submits.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this, but isn't there an easyer way, without a new Javascript function?

Comment: Yes there is an easier way... not passing parameters via URL and via POST at the same time and just pass your id parameter via POST in hidden field (as you don't seem to want to do), but perhaps this is already a feature of how you app works that is too late to fix.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't *need* to have anchors, you could solve this without JavaScript by submitting using [`button` elements](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_value.asp) instead:

```
<button name="id" type="submit" value="${vs.count}">${vs.count}</button>
```

Note that Internet Explorer, prior version 8, will submit the text between the `<button>` and `</button>` tags, while other browsers will submit the value.